# Converting a dictionary to a mathematical expression

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

```
{'YOU': {'HE': {'EST': 8, 'OLM': 6}, 'SLO': {'WLR': 8}},
 'ARE': {'KLP': {'EST': 6}, 'POL': {'WLR': 4}},
 'DOING': {'TIS': {'OIL': 8}},
 'GREAT': {'POL': {'EOL': 6}},
 'WORK': {'KOE': {'RIW': 8, 'PNG': 4}, 'ROE': {'ERC': 8, 'WQD': 6}},
 'KEEP': {'PAR': {'KOM': 8, 'RTW': 6}, 'PIL': {'XCE': 4, 'ACE': 8}},
 'ROCKING': {'OUL': {'AZS': 6, 'RVX': 8}}}
```

Need to perform a calculation on the numbers in dictionary.

```
    Eg: {'YOU': {'HE': {'EST': 8, 'OLM': 6}, 'SLO': {'WLR': 8}},
 'WORK': {'KOE': {'RIW': 8, 'PNG': 4}, 'ROE': {'ERC': 8, 'WQD': 6}}} for this example the output would be
```

- [(8+6)x8]+[(8+4)x(8+6)]
- [14x8]+[12x14]
- 112+168
- 280

Following is the code I tried :

```
a = [tuple([k]+list(v.keys())+list(j.values())) for k,v in data.items() for i,j in v.items()]
```

and it gives :

```
[('YOU', 'HE', 'SLO', 8, 6),
 ('YOU', 'HE', 'SLO', 8),
 ('ARE', 'KLP', 'POL', 6),
 ('ARE', 'KLP', 'POL', 4),
 ('DOING', 'TIS', 8),
 ('GREAT', 'POL', 6),
 ('WORK', 'KOE', 'ROE', 8, 4),
 ('WORK', 'KOE', 'ROE', 8, 6),
 ('KEEP', 'PAR', 'PIL', 8, 6),
 ('KEEP', 'PAR', 'PIL', 4, 8),
 ('ROCKING', 'OUL', 6, 8)]
```

Comment: so how should the output look like?

Comment: Why add sometimes and multiply sometimes? What are the rules?

Comment: So does this calculation only apply to the keys `YOU` and `WORK` in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules aren't well-defined, but I'll give it a shot anyway. I am assuming you only want this calculation to apply to keys `YOU` and `WORK` in your nested dictionary. I think a list comprehension will get pretty complicated, and it's more readable to work with loops.

For each key `YOU` and `WORK`, I summed up these two innermost sets of values `8+6, 8` for `YOU` and `8+4, 8+6` for `WORK`, multiplied these values together `14*8` for `YOU` and `12*14` for `WORK`, then added the products together to get the result = `280`

```
dict_nested = {'YOU': {'HE': {'EST': 8, 'OLM': 6}, 'SLO': {'WLR': 8}}, 
'ARE': {'KLP': {'EST': 6}, 'POL': {'WLR': 4}}, 
'DOING': {'TIS': {'OIL': 8}}, 
'GREAT': {'POL': {'EOL': 6}}, 
'WORK': {'KOE': {'RIW': 8, 'PNG': 4}, 'ROE': {'ERC': 8, 'WQD': 6}}, 
'KEEP': {'PAR': {'KOM': 8, 'RTW': 6}, 'PIL': {'XCE': 4, 'ACE': 8}}, 
'ROCKING': {'OUL': {'AZS': 6, 'RVX': 8}}}

keys = ['YOU','WORK']
result = 0
for key in keys:
    inner_keys = dict_nested[key].keys()
    # multiply the values together for the first values of the inner key
    inner_product = 1
    for inner_key in inner_keys:
        inner_product *= sum(list(dict_nested[key][inner_key].values()))
        # print(inner_product)
    result += inner_product
```

Output:

```
>>> result
280
```

Answer (score 0):

***NOTE***

*By any means* don't use `eval`, it is insecure ("eval is evil").

For more details about `eval` harmfulness (there are too many, I've just cherry-picked one) read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!).

***Some Inspiration Towards a Solution***

As others and smarter before me have noted, I haven't found any reasonable explanation regarding the operands assignment in the example you've provided.

However, this is a little try - hope it will help you with the challenge.

So here you go:

```
import json

d = {'YOU': {'HE': {'EST': 8, 'OLM': 6}, 'SLO': {'WLR': 8}}, 'WORK': {'KOE': {'RIW': 8, 'PNG': 4}, 'ROE': {'ERC': 8, 'WQD': 6}}}

# Convet dictionary to a string
r = json.dumps(d)

# Convert string to char list
chars = list(r)

# Legal chars needed for computing
legal_chars = ['{', '}', ','] + [str(d) for d in range(10)]

# Filtering in only legal chars
filtered_chars = [x for x in chars if x in legal_chars]

# Replacing the {} with () and , with +
expression = ''.join(filtered_chars).replace('{', '(').replace('}', ')').replace(',', '+')

# Evaluating expression
result = eval(expression)

# (((8+6)+(12))+((8+4)+(8+6)))=52
print(f'{expression}={result}')
```

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Why?

Comment: I like the approach, but you missed that there are some unspecified rules where sometimes we add, and sometimes we multiply.

Comment: @KennyOstrom You're much correct. Haven't found a reasonable explanation in OP operands assignment. Just wanted to give it a try, and maybe help him towards handling his challenge.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Noted for OP at the post regarding the operands incoherence.

Comment: Because I don't get why do we have to serialize data structure to perform calculation. Not to mention using infamous `eval`. You are filtering the input but which seems like a good idea but I wouldn't be surprised if arbitrary code can still be injected. Of course the code works but it's more like an entertaining show than something I'd like to see in production code. Good job anyway. Cheers :)

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I've enjoyed reading your comment, eval is indeed evil. This code just intended to run. On the rare cases I find eval useful (never in production code, of course), I put a warning notice regarding `eval` usage - thank you for reminding me.